# Java Standard _Question

Tags: java

```
Random random = new Random();
String randomLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
for (int n=0; n<=25; n++)
System.out.print(randomLetters.charAt(random.nextInt(randomLetters.length())));
```

when print random 26 letter  there duplicate letter  i want print random 26 letters without print duplicate letters

this result display to me

```
  FXNJZMQWFTSKLRRFHOYWGTIQPWBUILD
```

Comment: Then you don't need random letters do you? (You need to `shuffle` a `List` containing the 26 letters)

Answer (score 3):

As there are only 26 letters, I am assuming you just want the upper-case alphabet in a random order. To accomplish this, you should use the [`Collections.shuffle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) method. One way of doing so:

```
List<Character> letters = new ArrayList<>();
for (char letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++) {
    letters.add(letter);
}
Collections.shuffle(letters);
letters.forEach(System.out::print);
```

Note that, if you aren't using Java 8, the final line will not compile as it uses [`forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) and a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) - the equivalent loop in Java 7 would be as follows:

```
for (Character letter : letters) {
    System.out.print(letter);
}
```

(it is also valid to use `char` here, but I'm avoiding some auto-unboxing probably with no difference)

Answer (score 1):

you can use StringBuilder to delete the letter you print every time so you won't print it again

```
Random random = new Random();
String randomLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
for (int n=25; n>=0; n--){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(randomLetters);
    int index = random.nextInt(randomLetters.length());
    char c = randomLetters.charAt(index);
    System.out.print(c);
    sb.deleteCharAt(index);
    randomLetters = sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't create a `new StringBuilder` every iteration. Also, don't forget that deletion in an array is an `O(n)` operation; making this `O(n^2)` - a really rather unperformant solution; especially compared to a `shuffle` based approach.

Answer (score 0):

To print unique characters, I would take a list of numbers from 0 to 26, shuffle it and then, print the characters by iterating it, e.g.:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < 26 ; i++){
    numbers.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(numbers);
String randomLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
for(int index = 0 ; index < numbers.size() ; index++){
    System.out.print(randomLetters.charAt(numbers.get(index)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the index you just selected from the string. So if you change that string to a stringbuilder  you can use the function deleteCharAt(index).

Hope that helps.